# File Upload requiring user to Browse again after validation fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple file upload that works, file uploads fine, however if the form validation fails for any reason, it requires the user to browse for the file again. Is there any way to persist or repopulate the File control to prevent this? Here is a condensed version that demonstrates the problem:

View form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Orders", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Upload)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Upload, new {type = "file", accept = ".csv", @class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Upload)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
}
```

Action and model:

```
  public ActionResult Test(UploadForm form)
  {
      ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "invalid name");

      return View(form);
   }

    public class UploadForm
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase Upload { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The Name text box is getting repopulated as expected.

Comment: move form submission to ajax request and handle validation without page reloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ajax and jquery-validation plugin to perform client-side validation

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UploadForm form)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "invalid name " + Guid.NewGuid());

    return Json(
        ModelState
        .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Any())
        .Select(x => new
        {
            key = x.Key,
            errors = x.Value.Errors.Select(y => y.ErrorMessage)
        }
    ), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

.cshtml

```
@using WebApplication1.Controllers
@model UploadForm
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "myForm" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Upload)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Upload, new { type = "file", accept = ".csv", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Upload)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
}

<script>
    $('#myForm').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const $form = $(this),
            formData = new FormData($form[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                onAjaxFormError($form, data);
            }
        })

        return false;
    })

    function onAjaxFormError(form, errorResponse) {
        $.each(errorResponse, function (index, value) {
            // Element highlight
            var element = $(form).find('#' + value.key);
            element = element[0];
            highLightError(element, 'input-validation-error');

            // Error message
            var validationMessageElement = $('span[data-valmsg-for="' + value.key + '"]');
            validationMessageElement.removeClass('field-validation-valid');
            validationMessageElement.addClass('field-validation-error');
            validationMessageElement.text(value.errors[0]);
        });
    }

    var highLightError = function (element, errorClass) {
        element = $(element);
        element.addClass(errorClass);
    }

    var unhighLightError = function (element, errorClass) {
        element = $(element);
        element.removeClass(errorClass);
    }
    const defaults = {
        ignore: [],
        highlight: highLightError,
        unhighlight: unhighLightError
    };

    $.validator.setDefaults(defaults);
</script>
```